# How to execute Glassfish Web Service in Java Client

Tags: java, web-services, netbeans, glassfish

i would like to execute a Web Service in a Java Client. I created a "Web Service Client" in a "Java Application" with Netbeans (with "WSDL URL"). So far so good.

My Problem is now i don't know how to call my Service. I did a rightclick in my Code and clicked "Insert Code..." and than "Call Web Service Operation...".

Netbeans generate this code:

```
stormgs.GetLdevInfoService service = new stormgs.GetLdevInfoService();

    QName portQName = new QName("http://StormGS/", "GetLdevInfoPort");
    String req = "<getStorageInfo  xmlns=\"http://StormGS/\"></getStorageInfo>";

    try { // Call Web Service Operation

        Dispatch<Source> sourceDispatch;
        sourceDispatch = service.createDispatch(portQName, Source.class, Service.Mode.PAYLOAD);
        Source result = sourceDispatch.invoke(new StreamSource(new StringReader(req)));
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        System.out.println("damn " + ex);
    }
```

But im not sure if this work. Furthermore in the last line of the try-Block it throws me this Exception:

```
com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.ClientTransportException: HTTP transport error: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
```

Can anyone help me. I only want to call my Web Service in this Client. Thanks!